# How does GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread behave over the lifetime of an asyncronous thread?

Tags: c#, .net-core, benchmarking

What i'm unsure of, and unsure how to test:

If this will accurately reflect the memory usage of the thread througout its entire lifetime?

If there are other considerations needed to get an accurate value during the threads lifetime, such as when awaiting another task to complete within the thread itself?

MSDN has little information as to the intended behavior: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.getallocatedbytesforcurrentthread?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: an "asynchronous thread" is an oxymoron; async is specifically not tied to threads, and your *perceived* thread can bounce around at any `await`, at which point `GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread` is reporting largely unrelated things between calls...

Comment: @MarcGravell Meaning it will essentially reflect the memory allocated of every awaited task, and not just the current task?

Comment: meaning it could reflect *anything* that happened on a particular thread that is servicing a particular async continuation - in many cases that could mean random threads from the thread-pool, which could have been doing *anything*; but more complex threading models are possible with async

Comment: @MarcGravell That's understandable, but disappointing. I was hoping to be able to get memory usage of a specific awaited task within the thread. Thanks for the insight.